Line continuation followed by blank line in Fortran
I have a main program and a module.  I want the main program to use certain parts of the module under normal circumstances, but to use some added elements if compiled with a "DEBUG" cpp macro.  This is the way I have found to make this work:
    program myprogram
    
    use comp_module, only: data1, routine1 &
    #idef DEBUG
                           , debug_data, debug routine
    #endif
    ;
    ....

If I don't put that semicolon in at the end, the compiler thinks it's an error when not compiled for debugging.  So, this works.
It's just that it looks sort of inelegant with a leading comma in the debug line and a useless semicolon following.  And I can just see some developer coming along later, not getting what's going on, and re-introducing a compiler error.
What is a better way?

In this case you can just use two separate use declarations
use comp_module, only: data1, routine1
#idef DEBUG
   use comp_module, only: debug_data, debug routine
#endif


It's that simple???  OK.  Thanks.  Learn something new every day!

You've been told the best way to handle this: two separate USE statements. There are some additional, possibly educational, things to add. For example:

The "semicolon workaround" as presented was not legal before Fortran 2008
A "blank line" is a comment line

In Fortran 2003 a semicolon was not allowed at the start of a line: semicolons could be used only to separate statements "within a line". There are ways to modify the workaround here but, as it's not necessary with the better way and with Fortran 2003 being so old, I won't expand.
The compiler error mentioned comes from how continuation works in free-form source.  Once the & appears we've signalled that the line will be continued. Line continuation looks for the subsequent noncomment line:
   use mod, only : a &  ! The blank line which follows is ignored

   ! This is another comment line and is ignored, as is the next

   , b  ! This is another entity from mod

That is, the first noncomment line is taken as continuing the use statement. If that's not a semicolon or something which makes sense to USE, then the compiler will get upset.
Finally, there's a way with a single USE statement and no semicolon:
    use comp_module, only: &
    #idef DEBUG
                           debug_data, debug routine, &
    #endif
                           data1, routine1

This has little to recommend it.
